# The animate keyword is showing in red and not working

Tags: java, android, function

I'm creating an animation bulb app in which there are two image views having blue and green bulb and two buttons(named blue and green).

On pressing them the **image1's** opacity increases and **images2's** decreases, the opposite happens when the other button is tapped(alpha values are 1 for both initially), but the animate keyword is showing up in red and the code is not compiling.

**MainActivity :**

```
 package com.example.honey1.animatedbulb;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void greenTapped(View view)
{
    ImageView blue=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bluebulb);
    ImageView green=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.greenbulb);
    blue.animate.alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
    green.animate.alpha(0).setDuration(2000);

}
public void blueTapped(View view)
{
    ImageView blue=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bluebulb);
    ImageView green=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.greenbulb);
    blue.animate.alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
    green.animate.alpha(1).setDuration(2000);

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

**Main activity screenshot :**

[image: main activity screenshot]

**XML file screenshot :**

[image: XML file screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot **`()`** after `animate()`

And `animate()`  is method not a property

Use this

```
blue.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
green.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
```

Instead of this

```
blue.animate.alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
green.animate.alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be use like below code,  should use `.animate()` not `.animate`:

> The animate() method on a View object returns an ViewPropertyAnimator
>   object for the view.It provides a fluent API to typical animations
>   which can be performed on views.

Your code :

```
 blue.animate.alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
 green.animate.alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
```

Replace to :

```
  blue.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
  green.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

`View.animate()` is a method, not a property or field.